# Unit Testing - Challenges with Dynamic / Interrelated Repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, repository

I have a handful of controllers and each controller has a test class with unit tests.  Each unit test calls a single action and verifies that the action handles a given scenario.

The test class has a setup routine that instantiates a number of fake repositories and other fake objects.  The fake repositories have static collections that the repository methods/functions operate against.

It is working pretty well but I'm running into some challenges:

- When entities in one fake collection reference entities in another fake collection the code in the repository's constructor explodes and becomes difficult to manage
- When a unit test calls an action that modifies the fake repository data, the static collection changes state making it nearly impossible to operate against that same data in other unit tests

**So I have two questions that might require you to also explain your general approach:**

1. How do you go about setting up a fake collection for an entity that references other fake collections/entities?
2. Do your fake repositories support update/insert/delete operations?  If so, how do you prevent changes from one unit test from impacting another unit test?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your first issue a bit more - finding it  difficult to contextualise.

Comment: @Ahmad: Entities with relationships (i.e. an author has books, a book has authors and publishers, etc.).  Creating a list of authors, a list of books, etc. is pretty easy, but establishing the relationships between them (i.e. by calling add methods on the entities in the repository constructors) gets a bit messy.

Comment: Entities with relationships are common, that's what would form your domain model. Now I don't want to confuse things here, but it seems that what missing here is a further  understanding of repository design. Within DDD (Domain Driven Design), each aggregate has a repository - which kinda relates back to the relationships between entities

Comment: On a unrelated note, most examples apps use the service layer, repository layer, with an anemic domain model (classes with getters and setters). IMO thats become the mindset when creating asp-mvc apps - the problem with this I think is when you actually try to model and design something a bit more complex it falls over

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your repositories are abstracted with interfaces you could use a mock object framework to generate a fake repository and inject it into the controller being tested. Here are some popular choices:

- [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx)
- [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/)
- [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)

Answer (score 1):

With regards to point 2, why not setup the fake repository in the `Setup` function on your unit test class (which you do) and use the `TearDown` to reset the state of the repository after each test.

*(These are NUnit specific attributes, so I can't comment if other frameworks have the similar features).*

Comment: Thanks Ahmad - I didn't even know the TearDown attribute existed - I'll check on that.